# Recommend C++ library to split a file into chunks and merge it back?

Tags: open-source, c++

I have a input file(s) which can have size up to 25 GB. The file type may be a image, video, text, binary, etc. I want to know if I there's a cross-platform library that provides a way to split/join files.

Or if there's a class/function in C++ that provides me this kind of utility.

Comment: Why not use any of C++'s usual I/O systems? Read in the file and write it out in different files to split; read back the output files and concatenate to join. Or call the GNU coreutils `split` and `cat`.

Comment: Look at the source for `split` and `join` in Debian's `coreutils` package

Answer (score 1):

As @Kodiologist says this isn't too hard to do from first principles:

**Edit:** Simplify code.  Unfortunately the added complexity from being able to support any stream type is not helpful in this context.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

const int size1MB = 1024 * 1024;

std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> createChunkFile(std::vector<std::string>& vecFilenames) {
    std::stringstream filename;
    filename << "chunk" << (vecFilenames.size() + 1) << ".txt";
    vecFilenames.push_back(filename.str());
    return std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(filename.str(), std::ios::trunc);
}

void split(std::istream& inStream, int nMegaBytesPerChunk, std::vector<std::string>& vecFilenames) {

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[size1MB]);
    int nCurrentMegaBytes = 0;

    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> pOutStream = createChunkFile(vecFilenames);

    while (!inStream.eof()) {
        inStream.read(buffer.get(), size1MB);
        pOutStream->write(buffer.get(), inStream.gcount());
        ++nCurrentMegaBytes;
        if (nCurrentMegaBytes >= nMegaBytesPerChunk) {
            pOutStream = createChunkFile(vecFilenames);
            nCurrentMegaBytes = 0;
        }
    }

}

void join(std::vector<std::string>& vecFilenames, std::ostream& outStream) {
    for (int n = 0; n < vecFilenames.size(); ++n) {
        std::ifstream ifs(vecFilenames[n]);
        outStream << ifs.rdbuf();
    }
}

void createTestFile(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::trunc);

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[size1MB]);

    int i = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < 1024; ++n) {
        for (int m = 0; m < size1MB; ++m) {
            buffer[m] = 'a' + (i++ % 26);
        }

        ofs.write(buffer.get(), size1MB);
    }
}

int main()
{

    // Create test file

    std::string filenameBefore = "before-big.txt";
    createTestFile(filenameBefore);

    // Split

    std::ifstream ifs(filenameBefore);
    std::vector<std::string> vecFilenames;

    split(ifs, 100, vecFilenames);

    // Join

    std::string filenameAfter = "after-big.txt";

    std::ofstream ofs(filenameAfter, std::ios::trunc);
    join(vecFilenames, ofs);

    return 0;
}
```

This builds for me in Visual Studio 2015.  No reason why it shouldn't in any C++11 compiler (but I can't promise you won't have to make minor adjustments).

Here's a quick sanity check that the split and joined file is the same as the original

[image: compare md5 files]

The kind of error I'm checking for here is exactly the reason I'd prefer to rely on tried and tested code, but I'm not convinced `coreutils` is convenient to grab and use as a library.  To be honest, I'd probably end up just executing the `split` and `join` binaries as child processes from within my main program.